# Ubuntu 12.04 restart function

Tags: 12.04, restart

Problem with Dell Inspiron 1520 - dual boot: Windows XP and Ubuntu.
After updating Ubuntu 11.10 to Ubuntu 12.04 shutdown->restart function is not working.
Another problem: starting Grub (version 0.97) menu screen shows old Ubuntu 11.10 entries.
After selecting 11.10 entry, Logon screen shows Ubuntu 12.04  title.
Restart function does not work before or after logon - in both Unity and Gnome Classic (no effects) desktops. Terminal command:  "sudo reboot" works; "sudo shutdown -r now" does not work most of the time.
Problems corrected in Ubuntu 12.10 !!!

Answer (score 4):

Firstly; to update grub, run

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda (assuming /dev/sda is your hdd)
```

as for the restart, if you click the "shut down" button, restart is an option on the dialog which pops up.